# How to continue a condition statement after the first one is meet in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a program that transfers camel case words to snake words, for every capital case in the string(pretend the first letter is always lower case), it switches to a lower case and adds a "_" before it. I've been trying many ways and it only checks the first capital letter and then returns.

```
def main():
    camels = input("camelCase: ")
    print(snake(camels))


def snake(camels):
    while True:
        for camel in camels:
            if camel.isupper():
                a = camels.replace(camel, "_" + camel.lower())
                return a
                continue
            else:
                pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example, if the input is...

camelCase: helloPythonWorld

expected output: hello_python_world

output now: hello_pythonWorld

Comment: Maybe don't use `return` in the middle of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the `return`. Other problem is that if the first letter is uppercase the snake_case word will start with "_"

```
def snake(camels):
    a = camels
    i = 1
    for camel in camels[1:]:
        if (camel.isupper()):
            a = a[:i] + "_" + camel.lower() + a[i+1:]
            i += 1
        i += 1
    return a.lower()
```